# Pytorch nn.MSELoss without specifying target

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, loss-function, mse

I was having difficulty with my loss getting stuck at a particular value. It would always decrease to a certain value, then stop decreasing. The code regarding the loss was:

```
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
loss = criterion(y_pred, y_batch.unsqueeze(1))
```

When I changed it to:

```
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
loss = criterion(y_pred, target=y_batch)
```

the issue was fixed.

What was happening before when the target was not specified? Does the target need to be specified for every Pytorch loss function? I found nothing in the documentation about target specifications.

Comment: `target` is the name of the second positional argent, that's all. The only difference between your two snippets is the unsqueezing of `dim=1`.

Comment: Ah. Silly me. Thank you. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it, and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `target` is the name of the second positional argument, that's all. The only difference between the two lines is the unsqueezing of `dim=1` on the second one.